# Should I downvote an answer which has the correct concept to answer the question but has syntax errors?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes

in a recent case on SO, a particular user answered the question the right way but his answer had syntax errors and even some typos. Normally, as I've seen this happen before to other users and me as well, I downvoted the answer simply because of the syntax errors.

So should I downvote an answer which has the correct concept but has syntax errors?

The answer has since then been deleted.

Answer (score 15):

If an answer has a typo and the intent of the author is clearly the correct solution then just fix the typo.

You should be downvoting the post if the authors clear intent is to provide a solution that you feel is not correct (or otherwise not helpful).